# Saving an image with the input resolution

Tags: android, android-camera2

I've created a custom `camera2` android application such that, it should take an image of 4160 x 3120 and save to a file. Here's my code:

```
Image img = reader.acquireLatestImage();
if (img != null) {

     ByteBuffer imgBuffer = img.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
     imgBuffer.rewind();
     final byte[] bytes = new byte[imgBuffer.capacity()];
     imgBuffer.get(bytes);
     saveImage(bytes);

     img.close();
}
```

But the problem I'm having is, although I'm receiving the image (`img` object which has the desired height and width) with the correct resolution and it's saving, it's in low resolution. What I'm suspecting is that the `imageBuffer` capacity is causing the issue.

When setting up the camera, I initialized the instance as follows (with the max resolution):

```
ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, 2 );
```

And when creating a capture request, I use the following code:

```
final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
captureBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 0);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_QUALITY, (byte)100);
```

Comment: Which device is that? How do you request 4160 x 3120 ?

Comment: When I'm setting up the camera, I set the resolution to 4160 x 3120,  ImageReader.newInstance" part I've mentioned in the question. From the image instance I'm getting from: "Image img = reader.acquireLatestImage();", I can see it's resolutions as  4160 x 3120. But the problem is when I read it from the buffer.

Comment: How do you know that your device supports this resolution?

Comment: From the camera characteristics I can see the camera is supporting the required resolution (from output sizes of the StreamConfigurationMap).

Comment: Can the built-in Camera app on your device create images of this size?

Comment: Yes, It can create

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156333/discussion-on-q-46291873)